# Libreoffice Calc REGEX how get second match?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How get second match of REGEX?
For example:

A1: `11:33`

`=REGEX(A1;"\d{2}")` - gets 11, but I want 33!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to capture the second pair of digits (that's the one after the first) and replace everything with the captured value.

```
=REGEX(A1,"^.*?\d{2}.*?(\d{2}).*$","$1")
```

---

Edit:

From your comment on the other answer it seems like you don't have a string but a time. In that case regex is the wrong tool. Simply use `MINUTE()` to extract the minute portion of a time:

```
=MINUTE(A1)
```

Comment: @FreeStyler: What's your version? I tested it with 6.4.4.2 (x64) on Windows and it works fine there.

Comment: @FreeStyler: Also see the edit. You probably have a time, not a string?

Comment: Thank you! `=HOUR(A1)+4 & ":" & MINUTE(A1)` works for me!

Also my version of LOC 7.0.0.3 x64

Comment: @FreeStyler: If you just want to add 4 hours you can use `=A1+TIME(4,0,0)`, that seems simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on range of possible input values. Do you **always** need the last two number characters of the cell's content (paragraph)? If yes, then you could add a `$` so that the regex matches just for content at the end of the paragraph (see [the documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.5/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions)):

> `=REGEX(A1;"\d{2}$")`

See the following example (A1=`'11:33`; A2 contains the formula shown in A3 (using the FORMULA() function).

[image]